# Putting Value In A Variable And Using It In XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="type='LEVEL'">
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select = "value"/>
      <xsl:variable name="spaces" select = "'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces, 1, $myVar)"/>
   </xsl:when>
```

I have the above code in XSLT. myVar is a variable with values like (1 or 2 or 3).
I need to store the output of the following line of code in a variable and use it outside the when condition.

```
xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces, 1, $myVar)"/
```

I am not able to do it currently.
Could anyone suggest something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you could try the following.
Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Result>
<resultDetails>
    <resultDetailsData>
        <itemProperties>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <type>LEVEL</type> 
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">5</value> 
        </itemProperties>
    </resultDetailsData>
</resultDetails>
</Result>
```

Apply this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">


<xsl:template match="itemProperties">
    <xsl:variable name="fromOutputTemplate">
        <xsl:call-template name="output"/>  
    </xsl:variable>
    <out>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fromOutputTemplate"/>    
    </out>          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="output">
    <xsl:variable name="spaces" select = "'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myVar" select = "value"/>
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="type='LEVEL'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces, 1, $myVar)"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gives you this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    
        <out>     </out>
```

Is that the way you would want to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
You could declare the variables outside the when condition (even if some XPaths in their declaration would failed and return null), or use the output inside the when condition.
But, why do you use a choose if you want to use the output anyway ?
One last try, could be to declare the variable and use the choose inside its sequence constructor, something like this :

```
<!-- You declare the 'tool' variables alone -->
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select = "value"/>
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select = "'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0'"/>

<!-- For myVarSub you use a sequence constructor instead of the select way -->
<xsl:variable name="myVarSub">      
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="type='LEVEL'">    
            <!-- xsl:sequence create xml node -->
            <xsl:sequence select="substring($spaces, 1, $myVar)"/>
       </xsl:when>
    <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

After that, just output or use the variable when needed. If you don't add other when conditions, myVar will be null when the test is false. But, please note that's a xslt 2.0 solution, because of the xsl:sequence.